# How to add a wan consul node to remote server running consul

Tags: consul

my lon-primary-server ip is **10.8.0.2** but consul is looking on a different subnet.

```
{
"node_name": "phl-remote-server",
"bind_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"tun0\"}}",
"ui": true,
"client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
"data_dir": "/tmp/consul",
"datacenter": "phl",
"log_level": "INFO",
"enable_syslog": true,
"enable_debug": true,
"server": true,
"bootstrap_expect": 1,
"leave_on_terminate": false,
"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true,
"rejoin_after_leave": true,
"advertise_addr": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\"}}",
"advertise_addr_wan": "{{GetInterfaceIP \"tun0\"}}",
"retry_join_wan": ["lon-primary-server"]
}
```

> Nov 21 15:26:39 phl-pi-3 consul[1401]:
> 2020-11-21T15:26:39.897+0530 [WARN]  agent: Join cluster failed, will
> retry: cluster=WAN retry_interval=30s error= Nov 21 15:26:39
> phl-pi-3 consul[1401]: 2020-11-21T15:26:39.897+0530 [WARN]
> agent.server.memberlist.wan: memberlist: Failed to resolve
> lon-primary-server: lookup lon-primary-server on **192.168.1.1:53**: no
> Nov 21 15:26:39 phl-pi-3 consul[1401]: 2020-11-21T15:26:39.897+0530
> [WARN]  agent: (WAN) couldn't join: number_of_nodes=0 error="1 error
> occurred:
> * Failed to resolve lon-primary-server: lookup lon-primary-server on 192.168.1.1:53: no
> such host

What am I doing wrong in config? why retry_join_wan is not hunting down for the node in the wan ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`serf_wan`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_serf_wan_bind) configuration option to the same address as used in `advertise_addr_wan` so that Consul binds to the correct interface for WAN communication.